# How can I get value from an arrayadapter to pass it another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

Here I'm trying to send my value that gets from a spinner (array adapter) to another activity. I populate my spinner using json and my spinner is something like below.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, villageList);
        spinner_village.setAdapter(adp);

        spinner_village.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                try {
                    JSONObject villageObject = arrayList.get(position);
                    String villageId = villageObject.getString("id");
                    String villageName = villageObject.getString("name");
                    String villageCode = villageObject.getString("village_code");

                    Toast.makeText(Region.this, villageCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Now I'm trying to get **"villageCode"** to my on create a method so that I can pass this value to my another activity. What I've done so far is

```
        spinner_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Region.this, Participant_Details.class)
                    .putExtra("catment_code", **-----**);
            Region.this.startActivity(intent);
            Region.this.finish();
        }
    })
```

putextra is giving error. How can I resolve it or what is the problem.

Comment: show result of `villageObject`

Comment: If your code perfect then declare  `String villageCode` global

Comment: Please share the complete code of your activity/class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the string villageCode as global variable (You can make your variable global by declaring it in the class level ***It should not be inside any method in your class***) and then you extract the value of the string in your onClick method. Like so:

```
    spinner_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Region.this, Participant_Details.class)
                .putExtra("catment_code", villageCode); //the value is being set here
        Region.this.startActivity(intent);
        Region.this.finish();
    }
})
```